# Different results with exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT) and simple("${exchangeProperty.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT}")

Tags: properties, exception, apache-camel

Can someone explain the following behaviour:

```
from(...)  // exception is thrown here

    .onException(Exception.class)
        .handled(true)
        .to("direct:end")
        .end()

    ...

from("direct:end")

    .process(exchange -> {
        // prints: org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: ...
        log.debug(exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT).toString());
        })

    // prints: null
    .log(simple("${exchangeProperty.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT}").getText())

    .choice()
        .when("simple("${exchangeProperty.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT} != null")
            ...
```

...and how to work around it?

Comment: `EXCEPTION_CAUGHT` is String constant in Exchange interface with value `CamelExceptionCaught`. The property is saved under this key. So use `.log("${exchangeProperty.CamelExceptionCaught}")` or `.log("${exchangeProperty."+Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT+"}")`

Comment: @Bedla Thanks. If you make this an answer I'm going to accept it.